# Famous Question Badge @ 10K

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, badges, views

I noted a little discrepancy in awarding this badge. In my profile view I see 10K as the total views for [Spring @Transactional does not work in JUnit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718916/spring-transactional-does-not-work-in-junit-test) just when it has crossed 9.5K.

However, I still don't see Famous Question badge coming. In fact if I see the questions that got the Famous Badge the views are (correctly) over 10K.

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: It currently has 9533 views. Which is less than 10k, but rounds up to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The badge awarding script doesn't round. You need 10.000 views or more, not 9.5k rounded up to 10k.

The *user interface* on the other hand *does* round. If you want to know the precise number, hover over the number and look for the tooltip pop up. It'll tell you the exact number:

[image: tooltip showing exact number]